$b$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$ implies no pseudoprime to the base $b$ is divisible by $p^2$
I want to show that if $b$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$, then no (Fermat) pseudoprime to the base $b$ is divisible by $p^2$.
I've tried writing down the meaning of this: supposing that if $a$ is composite, but $a^{b-1} \equiv 1 \mod b$, and $p^2 \mid a$, I want to show that $\exists g \forall k: b^k \neq g \mod p^2$. But I'm struggling to relate the two different moduli $\mod b$ and $\mod p^2$, and I can't see where to bring in $a$.

"$N$ pseudoprime to the base $b$" means $b^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$. Hint : what you have to show is that $p^2\mid N$ implies $b^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p^2$ , so $b$ is not a primitive root of $p^2$.
